# Apply a multi column filter to AG Grid at once

Tags: javascript, filter, ag-grid

I have an ag grid with 10 columns.

How can an apply a multi column filter on this grid?

I am able to successfully apply a filter to a single column like so:

```
 var colToFilter='FirstName';
 var valueToFilterOn='Bob'


 var filter = gridOps.api.getFilterInstance(colToFilter);

 filter.setModel({values:valueToFilterOn};

 filter.applyModel();

 gridOps.api.onFilterChanged();
```

This works like a charm.

However, scenario two is, let's say I have 2 colums to filter on, say:

```
 var colToFilter1='FirstName';
 var colToFilter2='LastName';

 var valueToFilterOn1 = 'Bob';
 var valueToFilterOn2 = 'Smith';
```

Now if try to apply each filter individually, then it works. But I only see the data for either FirstName=Bob, or LastName=Smith - but I'm trying to apply both filters at the same time.

However, is somethiing like that doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a filter model that contains an array of filter conditions, with each filter condition specifying the column to filter on and the value to filter on

```
var filterModel = {
    operator: 'AND',
    conditions: [
        { colId: 'FirstName', type: 'equals', filter: 'Bob' },
        { colId: 'LastName', type: 'equals', filter: 'Smith' }
    ]
};

gridOps.api.setFilterModel(filterModel);
gridOps.api.onFilterChanged();
```